# PHP Delete issue

Tags: php, sql

I have a function to delete files from the admin side,
And it's not working.

**Function:**

```
 public function delete_project_files($fileID,$file_url) {

        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM  project_files WHERE file_id='$fileID'");

        echo $file_url;

        unlink("uploadData/$file_url");

        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><b>Project File Deleted.</b></div>";

}
```

**Error Message I am getting:**

> Warning: unlink(uploadData/) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in F:\Daxxip Projects\SRS CRM\Application\inc\TouchClass.php on line 406

My Class is inside an `inc/` folder and my files are storing to a folder called `uploadData`

Comment: You error is very clear. You user, which is user for your web-server, has not enough permissions to delete file.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: "Permission denied" - change the permission for the webserver user

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes but how i am in windows WAMP setup now.

Comment: Regarding the mysql_* can i just replace them all mysqli_* ? any issue? while i do i can see lot of errors.

Comment: Right click on the folder -> Properties -> Permissions, X_X ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your code:

```
echo $file_url;
chmod("uploadData/$file_url", 777);//add this line
unlink("uploadData/$file_url");
```

Give the 777 permission to your file which you are going to delete.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the process executing the PHP does not have the rights to delete that file. Maybe it is read-only, or the folder permissions prevent modifications on the content.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the folder now have only read permission. If you are uploading files to folder, you have to set the permission of that folder to read-write-execute. You can do this by Right clicking and setting permission to that folder.

Comment: I dont have any issue with uploading  the error is while deleting a file? Any issue in my code?

Comment: If you want to know issues with the query just echo the query as echo "DELETE FROM  project_files WHERE file_id='$fileID'"; exit; in the function and execute the query in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a ftp server on that location and run chmod 777 -R on the root of your project. That should give enough permissions to any file/function u may need for further use as well.